# Magento Page Title - include SKU as well as product name

Tags: magento

How do I include the SKU as well as the product name in the page title (when looking at the product details page)?

Cheers!

Comment: you edit the template and add the variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In app/design/frontend/default/{your theme Folder}/template/page/html/head.phtml you could try

```
<?php if ($_product = Mage::registry('current_product')) { ?>
    <title><?php echo $_product->getName() . ' ' . $_product->getSku(); ?></title>
<?php }else{ ?>
     <title><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></title>
<?php } ?>
```

You could also do this using an observer for `catalog_controller_product_view` see [Magento Change Product Page Titles to Include Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869335/magento-change-product-page-titles-to-include-attributes)

Comment: Can't believe I missed this reply until now! This resolves the issue perfectly, many thanks!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a collection already loaded (ie. on product view page)

```
$_product->getSku();
```

If for some reason you need to call this from a different template higher up in the chain that isn't already loading the product/collection, you can drop this one:

```
$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$_product->getSku();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had a clue about the code, but I still do not know how I get this to be added to the page title - I don't need to add it to the page contents (it is already on there), I need it on the browser title bar/tab. The template doesn't seem to use a different head section for the product view page, just one for all pages? How can I add product SKU to the page title without affecting the page title on pages which are not displaying a product?

Answer (score 0):

look at your design template in catalog/product/view.phtml file you should be able to simply do $_product->getData('sku');