# Magento Change Product Page Titles to Include Attributes

Tags: php, magento

I have 2 custom attributes I'd like to add to the `<title>` tags on product pages.  They are 'brand' and 'subtitle'.

My page title would end up something like this:

$brand." ".$productname." ".$subtitle;

How can I achieve this?

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: are you referring to the actual page title i.e. meta title or are you simply referring to how the product name appears on the product page?

Answer (score 22):

From your question, I assume you are referring to changing the meta title for products.

There are 3 options open to you:

1. Go through each product and manually update (or use a spreadsheet
   and import) each product meta title individually.  These values are
   available in the admin area when editing a product.
2. Rewrite Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View and override the
   _prepareLayout() method which is where this tag is being generated.
3. Use an observer and hook into catalog_controller_product_view event.

Your decision is really between options 2 & 3 (both of which will require you to create a custom module to achieve).

I always try to be as unobtrusive as possible when extending Magento core functionality - so I would opt for option 3 here.  Please see below code for a complete example:

app/etc/modules/Yourcompany_Yourmodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Yourcompany_Yourmodule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Yourcompany_Yourmodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Yourcompany/Yourmodule/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Yourcompany_Yourmodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Yourcompany_Yourmodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <yourmodule>
                <class>Yourcompany_Yourmodule_Model</class>
            </yourmodule>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_controller_product_view>
                <observers>
                    <yourmodule>
                        <class>Yourcompany_Yourmodule_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>catalog_controller_product_view</method>
                    </yourmodule>
                </observers>
            </catalog_controller_product_view>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Yourcompany/Yourmodule/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Yourcompany_Yourmodule_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * Change product meta title on product view
     *
     * @pram Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return Yourcompany_Yourmodule_Model_Observer
     */
    public function catalog_controller_product_view(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if ($product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()) {
            $title = $product->getData('brand') . ' ' . $product->getData('name') . ' ' . $product->getData('sub_title');
            $product->setMetaTitle($title);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for your answer.  Sorry to say, but I meant page title tags. Stackoverflow didn't except my formatting for `<title>` until I added backticks, so it just removed the word 'title'

Comment: Hi Lucas - this code will change the page title tag as you require

Comment: Thanks Drew, I was able to get this to work.  However, the 'brand' attribute does not seem to load.  It is a dropdown attribute in the backend. I tried `$product->getAttributeText('brand')` but with no success.  How can I retrieve this attribute?

Comment: @LucasScholten - not sure, getAttributeText is definitely the way to go.  Are you sure the product has a value selected for 'brand'

Comment: I am sure, I am able to call this value in the product view.phtml successfully.

Comment: Also it seems I was mistaken before when I said the code was working.  Only the product name appears.  The brand and subtitle do not.  I have caching and the compiler disabled.  Thanks for your help so far though, its really appreciated.

Comment: @LucasScholten - i have tested the code with both dropdown and text attributes.  All work fine.  If you var_dump the result from getAttributeText, do you get an empty string or false

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks again for your help.  I'm very new to this, how do I var_dump the result from getAttributeText?  So far I have gone into view.phtml and added Zend_Debug::dump($_product);  this shows that metatitle is unchanged.  It shows the brand on sample data products but this is only because the brand has been input into the name fields anyway.  I am using 1.7.0 community edition.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the simplest and best way to override META logics for product page in magento

copy **/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php** 
to **/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product**

and override **function _prepareLayout()**, my example goes bellow

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/breadcrumbs');
    $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');

    if ($headBlock) {
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $title = $product->getMetaTitle();

        // SEO values start
        $categoryCollection = $product->getCategoryCollection();
        foreach ($categoryCollection as $k) {
            $topCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($k->getId());
            break;
        }
        $brand = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
        $shortDescription = $product->getShortDescription();
        $suffix = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title_suffix');
        // SEO values end

        if (!$title) {
            $title = $product->getName() .' '.$brand. ' - '. $topCategory->getName() . $suffix;
        }


        $headBlock->setTitle($title);

        $keyword = $product->getMetaKeyword();
        $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
        if ($keyword) {
            $headBlock->setKeywords($keyword);
        } elseif($currentCategory) {
            $headBlock->setKeywords($product->getName());
        }

        $description = $product->getMetaDescription();
        if (!$description) {
            $description = $brand. ' '. $topCategory->getName() .'. '. $shortDescription;
        }
        $headBlock->setDescription( ($description) );


        // var_dump($title);
        // var_dump($description);


        if ($this->helper('catalog/product')->canUseCanonicalTag()) {
            $params = array('_ignore_category'=>true);
            $headBlock->addLinkRel('canonical', $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, $params));
        }
    }

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is addition to Drew Hunter's answer

magento includes category name into title so the proper solution would be:

```
class Yourcompany_Yourmodule_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * Change product meta title on product view
     *
     * @pram Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return Yourcompany_Yourmodule_Model_Observer
     */
    public function catalog_controller_product_view(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if ($product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()) {
            if ($category) {
                $title = $brand . ' ' . $product->getData('name') . ' - ' . $product->getData('category')->getData('name');
            } else {
                $title = $brand . ' ' . $product->getData('name');
            }
            $product->setMetaTitle($title);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you only want to change the product title on the catalog view page

In app/design/frontend/default/{your theme Folder}/template/page/html/head.phtml you could

```
<?php if ($_product = Mage::registry('current_product')) { ?>
    <title><?php echo $_product->getData('xyz') . ' ' . $_product->getName(); ?></title>
<?php }else{ ?>
     <title><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></title>
<?php } ?>
```

See [Get Attribute Name And Value Magento](http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/get-attribute-name-and-value-magento/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe Drew Hunter has provided most of the correct answer, but I had to make a few changes to get it to work (EE, 1.14.2.x):

**In config.xml:**

> Change the nodes `<yourmodule>...</yourmodule>` to >`<yourcompany_yourmodule>...</yourcompany_yourmodule>`

**In Observer.php:**

> Change `public function catalog_controller_product_view(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)` to `public function catalog_controller_product_view($observer)`