# How to change product page title programmatically in magento?

Tags: php, magento, page-title

I am creating store for books using magento.I want to change page title like "authorname by bookname" for every product page & also I want to change the title of each & every category page.

I tried doing this by adding module by following [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/) link & followed this 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869335/magento-change-product-page-titles-to-include-attributes) answer.
But still no luck.

I am very new to magento.It would be great if there is a better alternative for this.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Easy way create under your local folder a new Mage folder and create the same path folder for a Mage_Catalog_Product_View.
Then from the core code, copy and paste the View.php file.

fine this lines:

```
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/breadcrumbs');
    $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
    if ($headBlock) {
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $title = $product->getMetaTitle();
        if ($title) {
            $headBlock->setTitle($title);
        }
```

and do something like thise:

```
        ...
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        /*not sure how you saved the extra info you want to show, if     it's a text this will be works perfect*/            
        $author = $product->getAuthorName();
        /*bookname is the name of the product? if not get bookname from product data*/
        $bookname = $product->getBookname();
        $title =  $author . ' ' . $bookname;
        if ($title) {
            $headBlock->setTitle($title);
        }
        ....
```

Best,
GrinGo.

Comment: Hello GrinGo..I am sorry but I dint where to create which folder?

Comment: You need to create a locale folder under code folder, then create this path folders Mage > Catalog > Block > Product. Then copy the same View.php file from core then try to make the changes I mentioned above.

Comment: I am trying but still no luck.I dont kno where am i going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to overwrite the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View class and change the title using _prepareLayout() method.

Let me know if you need more help.

Best,
GrinGo.

Comment: Since I am very new to magento,Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Sure, give a moment and I'll send you a complete answer.